# how data storing in core data model (attributes)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am new to learning with ios . Here i start with core data. Here that tutorial link [core data](http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-to-core-data/).Here i understood about the model and creating attributes. It like after enter all data we have to press `save` then the entered data will save in model and also display in table view.
I know `managed object` are the object that are created by our aplication code to store data.

**My Doubt:**

After press `save` button. how the entered data are triggered to display in table view and also how that data are saving in model ( core data ). I am confused in this part.

When we entered all data and when we press `save` how that data are saving in core data and are displaying in table view. How it working.I am asking for in theoretical and practical way.

which method are triggered to `display` that data in table view. And how the `entered data are storing in core data (model)`

If we delete any data in tableview also that data are not showing in model. How , how that are working. When we press `save` how that data are saving in core data ( model - attribute )

example:

They use 3 attributes:

1. company
2. Name
3. version

I dont know how they are saving. please dont down vote.This is my first question, it will help for up coming begineers.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When we entered all data and when we press save how that data are saving in core data...

The save button has a `-save:` action that's triggered when you hit the button. That method looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    // Create a new managed object
    NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Device" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newDevice setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:@"name"];
    [newDevice setValue:self.versionTextField.text forKey:@"version"];
    [newDevice setValue:self.companyTextField.text forKey:@"company"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The important ideas in this method are:

- **managed object context:** The first thing the method does is to get a reference to the app's managed object context, i.e. the object that manages all the managed objects.
- **create a managed object:** Next, the method creates a new managed object that will contain the device information. It stores the data that you entered in the new object. The object already belongs to a managed object context because you have to specify a MOC when you create a managed object.
- **save the context:** The call in the conditional part of the `if` statement saves the context, i.e. writes its changes out to the persistent store.

Later in the tutorial, the `-save:` method is modified to also update existing objects. You can look at the code and see that that version of the method first checks to see whether the view controller is working with an existing object or not; if it is, then it changes that object instead of creating a new one.

> ...and are displaying in table view.

One of the standard `UIViewController` methods is `-viewDidAppear:`, and `DeviceViewController` overrides this method as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Fetch the devices from persistent data store
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Device"];
    self.devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

As you can see, this method does these things:

- **gets the managed object context:** You can't access Core Data objects without a MOC.
- **creates and executes a fetch request:** Fetch requests are the way that you retrieve specific objects from your Core Data store. The result of the fetch request is an array of objects, which is saved into the view controller's `devices` property.
- **reloads the table:** Sending the `-reloadData` message to a table tells it to (surprise) load a new set of data from its data source. The view controller is the table's data source, so when the table asks for new cells the view controller configures each cell using objects in its `devices` property.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explaniation. i have one doubt what is ` context` in this line `if (![context save:&error])`. And what is `persistent store`

Comment: `context` is the managed object context, an instance of `NSManagedObjectContext`. That, the persistent store, the persistent store coordinator, and the managed object model are some of the most important objects in any Core Data app, and you should read about them in the [Core Data documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html).

Comment: One last question, Does `context` are used to maintain the status of the object contained in the managed object context layer of core data stack,?

Comment: Yes, `context` is a pointer to the managed object context. That object is like a "scratch pad," i.e. you can make changes to objects in a context and those changes only exist in the context *until* you save the context, at which point the changes are written out to the persistent store.